# Spyder latest version

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Did any one face this issue while downloading the latest Anaconda3 and opened spyder?

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1173, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 301, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 248, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 474, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: What leads to that error?

Comment: i dont know, i installed anaconda3 and spyder within it, and when I tried to open the spyder app, I got this error !